# I want the enter key press to work as submit button and run the js function

Tags: javascript

I want if user enter the value and press enter key instead of submit button. The function calvol() should run and give the result.

HTML

```
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row inpdip">
          <div class="col diptext">
            <label for="dip">Dip</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="number" class="inpbox" id="dip">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">   
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-dark" id="myBtn" type="submit" onclick="calvol()">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row outputvol">
          <div class="col diptext ">
            Volume :
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <span class="" id="result"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

JavaScript

```
function calvol() {
var R = 10.5;
var L = 62.5;
var inputh = document.getElementById('dip').value;


if (inputh>210){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Dip is over the tank limit." ;
} else if (inputh<= 0) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Enter a higher number" ;
} else {
var h = inputh/10;
let TankVolume = L * (R * R * Math.acos((R - h)/ R) - (R - h) * Math.sqrt(2 * R * h - h * h));
let volume = Math.round(TankVolume);
console.log(volume)
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = volume +"  Liter" ;
}
}

var input = document.getElementById("dip");
input.onkeyup = function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
     calvol();
  }
}
```

I want if user enter the value and press enter key instead of submit button. The function calvol() should run and give the result.

Comment: Take a form element and add "onsubmit" event listener to it. And use preventDefault() to prevent the default behavior of the form. Or change type attribute of the button from "submit" to "button".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.